# Supply voltage of an op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, resistors

So if I want my op-amp to produce a 12.5V peak value, and my op-amp data sheet says that with a 15V supply, minimum voltage output swing is 10V, would this mean that a 17.5V is sufficient to produce a 12.5V output?

Comment: No @MarcusM - this should not have been edited to include the 741 as the target op-amp being proposed by the op. He clearly stated in a comment to me that the op-amp has a slew rate of 16 volts per microsecond and , on previous questions he has always been considering the LF351 (which a an SR of 16 volts per us). I am un-editing the question because clearly  he cannot be considering the 741 having this slew rate.

Comment: @Andyaka you're right.

Answer (score 1):

> would this mean that a 17.5V is sufficient to produce a 12.5V output?

Most likely, yes.

But it's also important to check that if it's safe to apply 17.5V to the opamp. If the voltage swing is given for V<sub>CC</sub>=15V then the max value of V<sub>CC</sub> could be 15V *(For example, LM324 and TL072 give the Voltage Swing values for max V<sub>CC</sub>)*. This should be checked from the datasheet.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the heads-up. Max vaue of the op-amp is 18V according to the datasheet

Comment: @Fiidisks if you're looking at the LM741 datasheets that I know (notice that *very* many companies have produced LM741, and the one you have might not be the one for which your datasheet is): yes, that's the maximum damage free supply voltage. It doesn't necessarily *work* at that voltage. Check twice that you actually have the LM741 for which that number is correct, and that the number is a recommended operating voltage, and not a maximum voltage.

Answer (score 0):

> - necessary headroom at 15V supply 5V
> - does this imply 5V necessary headroom at 17.5 V supply?

No. Not really. I mean, it might, it's not even unlikely, but there's no guarantee. If there's no other data in the datasheet to say that, I wouldn't count on it, and would start characterizing my opamp to make sure it works.

Anyway, get a different opamp. 5V headroom is bad, even for a 1970's opamp. The effort you'll be spending on working with the higher supply, and compensating the properties of this opamp (let me guess: LM741 or worse?) are more expensive than just buying a better opamp.

---

You confirmed it's the LM741. These things come in different variants, but I only know ones where the recommended maximum supply voltage is 18V or lower, so you're too close to that. Really, the LM741 is the wrong Opamp, practically everywhere, but especially here, and can't be used.

Comment: What other type of date can I see to confirm my question? And yea, its an LM741

Comment: @Fiidisks The LM741 is notoriously terrible; you should absolutely use a different op amp. Just scan through the offerings of your preferred distributor and they'll probably have much better ones for the same price.

Answer (score 0):

> *So if I want my op-amp to produce a 12.5V peak value, and my op-amp
> data sheet says that with a 15V supply, minimum voltage output swing
> is 10V, would this mean that a 17.5V is sufficient to produce a 12.5V
> output?*

That's pretty much a reasonable assumption for most op-amps. However, it's always worth checking the data sheet of an op-amp you pick to ensure that this is true.

For instance, you might want a peak-to-peak output signal of 25 volts and both the GBW product and supply rail specs seem good to go but, slew rate limiting may cause this not to work. Slew rate limiting affects larger peak-to-peak signals and is just "one more thing" to check before you can be satisfied that you have chosen the "right" op-amp.

Comment: Slew rate according to the datasheet is 16V/us and my singal is of a 50Khz frequency. This would mean it is suitable right?

Comment: 25 volts p-p at 50 kHz requires an op-amp slew rate **greater than** 7.854 volts per microsecond. See [this online calculator](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Slew-rate-calculator.php#answer2). And note this: @Fiidisks a 741 doesn't have the required slew rate (as per you comment below another answer). The LM351 does.

Comment: @Fiidisks In addition to the slew rate not being enough, the 741 also won't have the GBW for 50 kHz signal to have gain of 50 (if this is still the case like in your previous questions).